# Google Business review fetch API response 200 Status But Empty JSON Response

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I'm using the Google My Business API in our project to fetch google review. The javascript script iterates over the list of locations and fetches review for each location. I know the code works because the majority of the locations return review perfectly.

Method Details here
`Method : Post`
`URL : https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/accountId/locations/locationId/reviews?access_token=token`

The oAuth tokens are valid and not expired

Comment: Did you ever find out why this happened? I also have one account that returns a 200 Status and a body of `{}` even though the business has 130 reviews. All the rest of the businesses return the reviews as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint for listing reviews requires a GET method, not a POST.
source: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list